# How to deal with HOG feature arrays to use for classification in scikit-learn?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, anaconda, training-data, cascade-classifier

I want to extract HOG features from an image so that I can put them through a classifier (`AdaBoost.SAMME`, in particular, using scikit-learn: [multiclass Adaboost in scikit-learn ensemble](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_adaboost_multiclass.html#example-ensemble-plot-adaboost-multiclass-py)).

To do that, I need to convert the image into an array-like of `shape = [n_samples, n_features]`

But the output of extracting HOG features from the image is a 1D array.
This is the relevant part my code:

```
tree = io.imread('C:\\Users\\app\\Pictures\\treephoto1.jpg')
type(tree)
print tree.shape, tree.dtype

graytree = color.rgb2gray(tree)
ge = filter.canny(graytree)
fd, hog_image = hog(ge, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),
                    cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=True)
```

When I check `fd`, it's an array like this:

[image]

Let's take the first 9 rows and assume that this was the complete output from the `hog` function, and that this image from which I got the HOG features is the first image in my training dataset.

Then given that I have a thousand training images, how will this HOG information be represented as `X = [n_samples, n_features]`?

Will the line below be the first row of `X` that I can use as input to a classifier?

```
[1, [0.162, 0.168, 0.250, 0.114, 0.106, 0.044, 0.035, 0.059, 0.200, 0.149]]
```

Will this entire row of HOG values be considered as a single feature? Or is this wrong?
From what I understand, a training sample should conform to this format:

```
[sample_index, feature_1, feature_2, feature_3, ..., feature_x]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For scikit learn classifiers the data is represented in the form of a matrix of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`, as you rightly say. There is no need for a sample index (if ever you need one for other purposes, don't put it in the matrix you intend to pass to scikit learn).

Taking your example, one sample would be

```
samples = [[0.162, 0.168, 0.250, 0.114, 0.106, 0.044, 0.035, 0.059, 0.200, 0.149]]
```

This is a python list of samples. It contains one sample which is a list of your features. However, if you have a lot of numerical data it is essential that you keep it in memory contiguously. This is done using `numpy.ndarray`s. Converting your one sample matrix to an array is as easy as

```
import numpy as np
sample_array = np.array(samples)
```

Let's move on to several samples. I will copy the same one several times, but of course they would be different. Again this really should be an array, so

```
samples =  np.array(
               [[0.162, 0.168, 0.250, 0.114, 0.106, 0.044, 0.035, 0.059, 0.200, 0.149],
               [0.162, 0.168, 0.250, 0.114, 0.106, 0.044, 0.035, 0.059, 0.200, 0.149],
               [0.162, 0.168, 0.250, 0.114, 0.106, 0.044, 0.035, 0.059, 0.200, 0.149]])
```

This sample matrix can be fed into a classifier, usually it takes the role of `X`.

Comment: Okay I'm confused - then what value does *n_samples* have to hold, in the shape *[n_samples, n_features]*? The array you constructed seems to me to only be *[n_features]*. If I have a thousand training images, would the classifier take in *[1000, samples]*? Or simply *[samples]*?

Comment: Also - you mentioned that *sample_array* is the matrix for one sample image, but you also called it a "list of features". But I'm using **only** HOG descriptors, no other features. So despite having an entire array of values, this is still going to be taken in as only HOG features, right? And so, if I were to use another feature apart from HOG, then would one sample look like this: np.array([set of HOG features],[set of second type of features]])? I'm kind of new to computer vision, so I'm not that familiar with the terms...

Comment: in the array I called samples you have hog descriptors for 3 images. Each image is represented by one line. Each image is a sample. The number of images you use is n_samples. The number of HOG features per image is n_features. "n_samples" and "n_features" just describe the number of inputs and the size of each input respectively

Comment: But if this is the case, then training images must all the be the same size, right?

Comment: your feature vectors must be the same size. Usually you extract HOG features from equally sized windows sweeping over your images. So yes, in effect it is best to have the same size for your samples

Comment: Would you say the size constraint ought to apply to input images as well? So when I get in real-world data, should it too be resized before being processed?

Comment: @user961627 test inputs should always live in the same space as the training set, since the model has learned to work in that space. The same preprocessing should be applied to both.

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008447/classification-test-in-scikit-learn-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a