# Classification test in Scikit-learn, ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Using the [tutorial on multiclass adaboost](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_adaboost_multiclass.html), I'm trying to classify some images that have two classes (but I don't suppose the algorithm shouldn't work if the problem is binary). Then I'm going to extend my samples to include other classes.

My current test is quite small, only 17 images in all, 10 for training, 7 for testing.

For now I have two classes: `0: no vehicle, 1: vehicle present`
I used integer labels because according to the example in the link above, the training data consists of integer-based labels.

I've edited the provided example only a bit, to include my own image files, but I'm getting an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\carclassify.py", line 66, in <module>
    bdt_discrete.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\weight_boosting.py", line 389, in fit
    return super(AdaBoostClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\weight_boosting.py", line 99, in fit
    X = np.ascontiguousarray(array2d(X), dtype=DTYPE)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 408, in ascontiguousarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order='C', ndmin=1)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The following is my code, adapted from the example on the scikit-learn website:

```
f = open("PATH_TO_SAMPLES\\samples.txt",'r')
out = f.read().splitlines()
import numpy as np

imgs = []
tmp_hogs = []
# 13 of the images are with vehicles, 4 are without
labels = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

for file in out:
        filepath = "C:\PATH_TO_SAMPLE_IMAGES\\" + file
        curr_img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread(filepath))
        imgs.append(resize(curr_img,(60,40)))
        fd, hog_image = hog(curr_img, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),
                 cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=True)
        tmp_hogs.append(fd) 

img_hogs = np.array(tmp_hogs)
n_split = 10
X_train, X_test = img_hogs[:n_split], X[n_split:] # all first ten images with vehicles
y_train, y_test = labels[:n_split], labels[n_split:] # 3 images with vehicles, 4 without

#now all the code below is straight off the example on scikit-learn's website

bdt_real = AdaBoostClassifier(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2),
    n_estimators=600,
    learning_rate=1)

bdt_discrete = AdaBoostClassifier(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2),
    n_estimators=600,
    learning_rate=1.5,
    algorithm="SAMME")

bdt_real.fit(X_train, y_train)
bdt_discrete.fit(X_train, y_train)

real_test_errors = []
discrete_test_errors = []

for real_test_predict, discrete_train_predict in zip(
        bdt_real.staged_predict(X_test), bdt_discrete.staged_predict(X_test)):
    real_test_errors.append(
        1. - accuracy_score(real_test_predict, y_test))
    discrete_test_errors.append(
        1. - accuracy_score(discrete_train_predict, y_test))

n_trees = xrange(1, len(bdt_discrete) + 1)

pl.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

pl.subplot(131)
pl.plot(n_trees, discrete_test_errors, c='black', label='SAMME')
pl.plot(n_trees, real_test_errors, c='black',
        linestyle='dashed', label='SAMME.R')
pl.legend()
pl.ylim(0.18, 0.62)
pl.ylabel('Test Error')
pl.xlabel('Number of Trees')

pl.subplot(132)
pl.plot(n_trees, bdt_discrete.estimator_errors_, "b", label='SAMME', alpha=.5)
pl.plot(n_trees, bdt_real.estimator_errors_, "r", label='SAMME.R', alpha=.5)
pl.legend()
pl.ylabel('Error')
pl.xlabel('Number of Trees')
pl.ylim((.2,
        max(bdt_real.estimator_errors_.max(),
            bdt_discrete.estimator_errors_.max()) * 1.2))
pl.xlim((-20, len(bdt_discrete) + 20))

pl.subplot(133)
pl.plot(n_trees, bdt_discrete.estimator_weights_, "b", label='SAMME')
pl.legend()
pl.ylabel('Weight')
pl.xlabel('Number of Trees')
pl.ylim((0, bdt_discrete.estimator_weights_.max() * 1.2))
pl.xlim((-20, len(bdt_discrete) + 20))

# prevent overlapping y-axis labels
pl.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.25)
pl.show()
```

### Edit

I typed

```
print tmp_hogs
```

and the output was this:

```
[ array([ 0.27621208,  0.11038658,  0.10698133, ...,  0.08661556,        0.04612063,  0.0280782 ]), 
        array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ..., -1.29909838e-15,  -7.01780982e-17,  -1.24900943e-15]), 
        array([ 0.0503603 ,  0.1497235 ,  0.2372957 , ...,  0.07249325, 0.04545541,  0.00903818]), 
        array([ 0.27299191,  0.13122109,  0.0719268 , ...,  0.0848522 ,  0.04789403,  0.01387038]), 
        array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,  3.32140617e-17,  -6.58924128e-17,  -6.23567224e-16]), 
        array([ 0.37431874,  0.18094303,  0.01219871, ...,  0.06501856, 0.04855516,  0.02439321]), 
        array([ 0.41087302,  0.16478851,  0.03396399, ...,  0.09511273, 0.04077713,  0.03945513]), 
        array([ 0.17753915,  0.07025565,  0.09136909, ...,  0.03396507, 0.01379266,  0.01645722]), 
        array([ 0.40605587,  0.05915388,  0.03767763, ...,  0.08981079, 0.05452031,  0.01725399]), 
        array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.00579303, 0.02053979,  0.0019091 ]), 
        array([ 0.31550735,  0.11988131,  0.07716529, ...,  0.09815158, 0.03058497,  0.02236517]), 
        array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ..., -3.51175682e-16,   1.31619418e-03,   2.86127901e-16]), 
        array([ 0.21381704,  0.22352378,  0.11568828, ...,  0.06311083, 0.02696666,  0.00402261]), 
        array([ 0.17480064,  0.1469145 ,  0.16336016, ...,  0.05614001, 0.03244093,  0.00524034]), 
        array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.03089959, 0.00509584,  0.00247698]), 
        array([ 0.04711166,  0.0218663 ,  0.05316   , ...,  0.04214594, 0.04892439,  0.25840958]), 
        array([ 0.05357464,  0.00530857,  0.07162301, ...,  0.06802692, 0.08331959,  0.26619977])]
```

Then I ran

```
print img_hogs
```

and the output was:

```
[ array([ 0.27621208,  0.11038658,  0.10698133, ...,  0.08661556, 0.04612063,  0.0280782 ])
 array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ..., -1.29909838e-15,  -7.01780982e-17,  -1.24900943e-15])
 array([ 0.0503603 ,  0.1497235 ,  0.2372957 , ...,  0.07249325, 0.04545541,  0.00903818])
 array([ 0.27299191,  0.13122109,  0.0719268 , ...,  0.0848522 , 0.04789403,  0.01387038])
 array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ..., 3.32140617e-17,  -6.58924128e-17,  -6.23567224e-16])
 array([ 0.37431874,  0.18094303,  0.01219871, ...,  0.06501856, 0.04855516,  0.02439321])
 array([ 0.41087302,  0.16478851,  0.03396399, ...,  0.09511273, 0.04077713,  0.03945513])
 array([ 0.17753915,  0.07025565,  0.09136909, ...,  0.03396507, 0.01379266,  0.01645722])
 array([ 0.40605587,  0.05915388,  0.03767763, ...,  0.08981079, 0.05452031,  0.01725399])
 array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.00579303, 0.02053979,  0.0019091 ])
 array([ 0.31550735,  0.11988131,  0.07716529, ...,  0.09815158, 0.03058497,  0.02236517])
 array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ..., -3.51175682e-16,   1.31619418e-03,   2.86127901e-16])
 array([ 0.21381704,  0.22352378,  0.11568828, ...,  0.06311083, 0.02696666,  0.00402261])
 array([ 0.17480064,  0.1469145 ,  0.16336016, ...,  0.05614001, 0.03244093,  0.00524034])
 array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.03089959, 0.00509584,  0.00247698])
 array([ 0.04711166,  0.0218663 ,  0.05316   , ...,  0.04214594, 0.04892439,  0.25840958])
 array([ 0.05357464,  0.00530857,  0.07162301, ...,  0.06802692, 0.08331959,  0.26619977])]
```

Comment: Quite independently of the error: 17 samples is decidedly not enough to do anything meaningful. Why don't you download a standard image database and try it on that? An easy, well organized one is Caltech101.

Comment: Could you show what `tmp_hogs` and what `img_hogs` looks like?

Comment: Sure! I've edited the question to include the outputs at the end.

Comment: The second output doesn't look right (it is a copy of the first). It should say array([... ... ... ...], dtype= ...)

Comment: I just tried **img_hogs = np.array(tmp_hogs, dtype =float)**, but it gave the same error, and on this line in fact.

Comment: what does [len(hog) for hog in tmp_hogs] return? Are they all the same? What about [hog.dtype for hog in tmp_hogs]?

Comment: No, the lengths are not all the same, but the dtype for all of them is the same, it's **float64**. I'm surprised why the lengths are different! I did resize the images to *(60,40)* before taking the hog features. The lengths that are output are between 1344 to 7600! But a lot of them do have common lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
imgs = []
tmp_hogs = np.zeros((17, 256))
# 13 of the images are with vehicles, 4 are without
labels = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

i = 0
for file in out:
        filepath = "C:\PATH_TO_SAMPLE_IMAGES\\" + file
        curr_img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread(filepath))
        imgs.append(resize(curr_img,(60,40)))
        fd, hog_image = hog(curr_img, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),
                 cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=True)
        tmp_hogs[i,:] = fd
        i+=1

img_hogs = tmp_hogs
```

Comment: Just tried this, but on the line *tmp_hogs[i,:]=fd*, I get the following error: **ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1728) into shape (256)**. So I adjusted the *tmp_hogs* declaration and gave it 1728 columns, then I got the same error again, this time saying it couldn't "broadcat from 1728 to 2080".  So I'm guessing this means that my *tmp_hogs* doesn't have the same number of columns in each row? But I resized all images to *60,40*! So how could this be?

Comment: limit the number of hog features. its not consistent

Comment: How so? I thought resizing the image to the same size would limit this.