# Limiting/controlling the number of hog features generated by scikit-image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

Following up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008447/classification-test-in-scikit-learn-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a/23015393?noredirect=1#comment35156661_23015393), I'm able to get the HoG features of an image into a numpy array that can be used for classification, but the number of HoG features of each image are different.

So for example, one image produces an array of HoG features that has 2080 elements, and another an array of 1744, and so on.

How can the number of HoG features generated be controlled? With *m* samples, I need to pass on an array of size *m x n* to a machine learning algorithm, so *n* needs to be constant. What I'm surprised about is that I've already resized all the images to the same size before extracting their HoG features, then why the difference?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? It's hard to tell without.

Comment: Scikit-image's hog features should be a consistent size given input images of the same size. I have never seen it give inconsistent sizes in the past provided all the images are the same size/shape

Comment: @user2970139, sure, all my code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008447/classification-test-in-scikit-learn-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a/23015393?noredirect=1#comment35156661_23015393
And if you want to replicate the error, the samples I used are all mentioned in a list on this page:
http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/15391/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-during-scikit-learn-classification

Answer (score 0):

If the input images are of the same size, then the features vectors from HOG will also be the same size provided you use the same parameters for the hog function for both input images.
For the hog feature vectors to be the same size, we must meet the following conditions across all input images,

1) same image size(resolution).
2) same number of cells.
3) same number of blocks.
4) same number of orientations.

As for the number of pixels in each cell, it does not need to be same across all input images to get same size feature vector as the block size and overlap also has a part in it. But it will directly affect the comparison between two feature vectors, so it is important to use same cell size across all input images for the sake of desirable results from descriptor comparison.

Though overlap parameter will improve the descriptor, it will not affect the feature vector size.